# Is there a way to check if there is a next element on a String array?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a string and I split it into word by word

```
String s = "Apple Orange Banana Grapes";
String s2[] = s.split("\\s+");
```

`s` value is changing that's why I can't be sure how many elements on `s2` can be made. Is there a way to check if there is still a next element on `s2`?

Example:

```
String s = "Pencil Eraser Pen";
String s2[] = s.split("\\s+");
```

As you can see the `s` now has 3 words compared to the other example therefore `s2[]` now has 3 elements. The next element of `s2[0]`, `s2[1]`, exists but the next element of `s2[2]` does not exist. I'm using Java by the way.

Comment: How are you using `s2`? You should be looping to get its values, using an index starting at zero and going to `s2.length - 1` inclusively.

Comment: @nickb Or, in more Java style, `for(String item: s2)`.

Comment: May I ask why you changed your acceptance vote?

Comment: Sorry, accidentally clicked it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check to see if the index is out of the range of the array.  You can find the length of the array by accessing the `.length` property of a `String[]`.

Therefore, the code that you would use if `i` holds the index in the array (e.g. `s2[i]`) is `if (i < s2.length - 1)`.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot `.length` exists.

Answer (score 1):

I think the construct you are seeking is a `for` loop.  You can iterate over the array you obtain from splitting the fruit string by whitespace.

```
String s = "Apple Orange Banana Grapes";
String s2[] = s.split("\\s+");
for (String fruit : s2) {
    System.out.println(fruit);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Apple
Orange
Banana
Grapes
```